# PHP - checking for unicode characters - doesn't work with newlines?

Tags: php, regex, unicode, newline

I'm trying to write a PHP script for some form validation. One of the requirements for a text input is that it must contain at least one unicode character. I wrote this function to check for this.

```
function containsLetters($str)
{
    return preg_match('/\p{L&}+/', $str);
}
```

It seemed to work fine for the first couple of test cases I wrote for it. But then I tried to test it against the string "\n", expecting a false result. Instead, it seems to completely crash.

I tried out this as well:

```
var $test = preg_match('/\p{L&}+/', "\n");
var_dump($test);
```

which also doesn't run.

Comment: shows an error https://regex101.com/r/iL7jL1/1

Comment: Hmm. I got this from http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html. 

It says "\p{L&} or \p{Cased_Letter}: a letter that exists in lowercase and uppercase variants (combination of Ll, Lu and Lt)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second attempt, you're trying to assign the call to a variable, **don't** ...

```
var_dump(preg_match('/\p{L&}/', "\n")); // int(0)
```

Also, you can just use `\pL` instead and be sure to enable the `u` (unicode) modifier ...

```
function containsLetters($str) {
    return (bool) preg_match('~\pL~u', $str);
}
```

Comment: Ok, makes sense. These work for me as well. However, I tried do var_dump(containsLetters("\n")); which did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry, nevermind. You are correct, it was an error with my use of parentheses.